# Mysql query taking around 10 minutes to execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query to fetch total amount and tax amount for each bill.

```
SELECT b.bill_no
     , b.total_amount
     , b.created_at
     , b.id
     , ( SELECT sum(gst_amt) 
        FROM bill_contents_pharmacy bc 
       WHERE bc.bill_id = b.id) as tgst 
  FROM bills b 
 WHERE b.bill_type = 'pharmacy' 
   AND cast(b.cr_at as date) >= '2017-08-01' 
   AND cast(b.cr_at as date) <= '2017-08-23' 
   AND b.is_cancelled = 0 
   AND b.is_deleted = 0 
 ORDER 
  BY b.bill_no ASC
```

This query is taking around 10 minutes inside my php code, but when I run it in phpmyadmin it's done in just 3.6 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely you're not executing the exact same query or not with the same database.

Comment: well unless you post the php code how can we tell?

Comment: 3.6 seconds is pretty much as well. How many records are you dealing with?

Comment: The PHP code must have something to do with it.  Do you know exactly how the result set is making it back to your code?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it's the exact same query and the same database. I have cross checked it, and I'm getting the same results. Only that it takes longer

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using yii2.

    $conn = Yii::$app->getDb(); and
    $result = $conn->createCommand($q)->queryAll(); are the only lines of code

Comment: And the PHP code does nothing more than execute it? No processing results or anything that could explain it? Run explain on it on both sides to get the query plan and see what's different

Comment: If my hypothesis were correct, and the size of the result set had something to do with it, then you could test this by using `LIMIT` on your query from PHP.  E.g. if the query returned 10K records, then limit to 5K and see how the return time is affected.

Comment: I don't know why everyone's fussing about PHP. Please provide CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . I have added LIMIT 1000 to the query and it took 132 seconds in phpmyadmin, and around 144 seconds in my php code.

Comment: This is happening because at the time of execution the query is taking different execution plan while executing from phpmyadmin is taking another execution plan,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can try This and you have to create relationship on bills and bill_contents_pharmacy tables and create index.

```
SELECT b.bill_no, b.total_amount, b.created_at, b.id, sum(bc.gst_amt) as tgst
FROM bills b
JOIN bill_contents_pharmacy bc ON bc.bill_id = b.id
WHERE b.bill_type = 'pharmacy'
AND cast(b.cr_at as date) >= '2017-08-01'
AND cast(b.cr_at as date) <= '2017-08-23'
AND b.is_cancelled = 0
AND b.is_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY b.bill_no, b.total_amount, b.created_at, b.id
ORDER BY b.bill_no ASC
```

This must Speed up your query

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that subquery. Try using a join instead.

```
SELECT b.bill_no, b.total_amount,b.created_at, b.id, sum(bc.gst_amt) as tgst 
FROM bills b LEFT JOIN bill_contents_pharmacy bc ON (bc.bill_id = b.id)
WHERE b.bill_type = 'pharmacy' AND cast(b.cr_at as date) >= '2017-08-01' 
AND cast(b.cr_at as date) <= '2017-08-23' 
AND b.is_cancelled IS FALSE AND b.is_deleted IS FALSE 
GROUP BY b.bill_no, b.total_amount, b.created_at, b.id
ORDER BY b.bill_no ASC
```

Also the casting to date may not be necessary.

Comment: this does not explain "This query is taking around 10 minutes inside my php code, but when I run it in phpmyadmin it's done in just 3.6 seconds."

Comment: actually it could